# CakePHP code protection encryption copyright

Tags: php, cakephp, encryption

I have developed a school management system software in CakePHP and I want to sell it to a school. Is there any way to encrypt it or such a thing that no one can copy it even having the code as is a offline system?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better will be selling as SaaS ([Software as a Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service))